# Unable to launch firefox48 with custom profile using geckodriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

**Expected Behavior -**

geckodriver should be able to launch Firefox48 with custom profile

**Step to reproduce -**

```
01: Zip default profile folder

02: Getting default profile location
string prof = (@"...\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6uqm9vnl.default.zip");

03: Converting to base64-encoded string
var prof1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prof);
var prof2 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(prof1);
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(prof2);

04: Initializing FirefoxDriver
new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

**Actual Behavior -**

geckodriver still launches new profile

Comment: Hi Automation, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask you to [edit] your question to clarify it a bit? For one thing, I'm not sure what you mean by "default profile"; and for another thing, you seem to be describing two different situations in your examples - one situation with a specified profile, and one without. Can you explain which one you're after, and in the case of the error, give more precise information about what the error is?

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply,
I have updated the question

Comment: Small help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had recently similar problem - the only difference is I point to a folder with whole FF profile
The solution in my case was:
1)I created a brand new profile with all extensions/credentials etc. I need during tests
2)I create driver like following:

```
    var profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Gecko_Profile")
    {
        EnableNativeEvents = false
    };

    var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    var options = new FirefoxOptions
    {
        Profile = profile
    };

    return new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

PS:Tested and working with: FF v48.0/v49.0.2/vFF50.0 + GeckoDriver v0.11.1 + WebDriver v3.0.1
PSS:GeckoDriver from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriver.GeckoDriver/)